# How to run Powershell script on Sharepoint Online at 9 o'clock P.M

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell

I want to run a Powershell script each day at 9:00 PM. How could it done this ?

Comment: Have you tried scheduling your script using task scheduler?

Comment: Not, but how and where ? Have You got any tutorial on it ?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383614(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: But how to shedule in Sharepoint Online.

Answer (score 1):

An alternate answer to windows scheduled tasks is to use [Azure Functions](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/functions/). These allow you to run powershell scripts on a schedule (or based on other events as well). An advantage is that your script would be in the cloud, so no servers to worry about maintaining. A downside is that there will be some costs associated with running the function each day.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot schedule a PowerShell script to run IN the SharePoint Online farm as you could with on prem. With SPO the script runs under a client context. That means you have to schedule the script to run on a computer that is online and connected to SPO at trigger time. If this computer isn't a dedicated server on prem or hosted in Azure, it would be your local PC. All cases are done as follows:

- If Task Scheduler is not open, start Task Scheduler.
- Find and click the task folder in the console tree that you want to create the task in.
- In the Actions Pane, click Create Task .
- On the General tab of the Create Task dialog box, enter a name for the task. Fill in or change any of the other properties on the General tab.
- On the Triggers tab of the Create Task dialog box, click the New… button to create a trigger for the task, and supply information about the trigger in the New Trigger dialog box.
- On the Actions tab of the Create Task dialog box, click the New… button to create an action for the task, and supply information about the action in the New Action dialog box. This is where you'll configure your PowerShell script as well as run time parameters for it.
- (Optional) On the Conditions tab of the Create Task dialog box, supply conditions for the task.
- (Optional) On the Settings tab of the Create Task dialog box, change the settings for the task.
- Click the OK button on the Create Task dialog box.

For more detail see [this article](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc748993(v=ws.11).aspx).