# How to execute a PowerShell script at a specified time

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, timer-jobs, power-automate, modern-team-site

I'm using SharePointOnline's Modern UI.

I want to execute a PowerShell script for updating SharePoint permissions at a specified time.
Is there a way to achieve this using PowerAutomate or some other method or service?
Ideally, there are no additional costs.

I would appreciate any ideas or pointers.

Answer (score 1):

If you are running the PowerShell from a Windows machine then you can use Windows Task Scheduler to schedule the running of your PowerShell script.

To run the PowerShell script from a cloud environment, you could run the PowerShell using an Azure function which can either be on a schedule or triggered via Power Automate.

Comment: Azure function is free?

Answer (score 1):

1.[Azure Automation](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/automation/) is an option for you to execute PowerShell script at a specified time.

2.You could schedule your PowerShell script by using task scheduler.

References:

[How to run Powershell script on Sharepoint Online at 9 o'clock P.M](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/210706/how-to-run-powershell-script-on-sharepoint-online-at-9-oclock-p-m)

[Task Scheduler for developers](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/taskschd/task-scheduler-start-page?redirectedfrom=MSDN)

[How To Automatically Run PowerShell Scripts at a Scheduled Time](https://redmondmag.com/articles/2016/05/13/automatically-run-powershell-scripts-at-a-scheduled-time.aspx)

Comment: Thank you for your information. Azure Automation is free?

Comment: You could start free.